# Samba problem -- is it a firewall issue?

Tags: networking, windows, samba, firewall

I have just installed Ubuntu 13.10 on a computer I use as archive for other machines.  I need Samba working from various Windows 7 machines.

I have confirmed that smbd and nmbd are both working, and the shares I need are set up correctly.  However, I can't use `net use ...` command from a Windows box to connect to the Ubuntu machine.  It would appear like a firewall issue on Ubuntu (I can get to other Windows machines on the system, so I'm pretty sure the issue isn't on the Windows side).

How can I check the firewall settings?

Answer (score 0):

You can print out firewall settings by opening terminal and executing

```
sudo iptables -L
```

This will print all active firewall rules. Specifically, you want to look for rules under `Chain INPUT` header.